# T4 doesnt generate KEY when key exists in database view & in EDMX

Tags: edmx, entity-framework-6.1, edmx-designer

We are using EF6.1.1
I have a database view. The view has "ID" column and is not nullable. I added that view on edmx designer. I notice the key icon infront for "ID" column in the designer. When I right click on "ID" column on the designer I also notice "Entity Key" option is selected
But when T4 regenerates entities, I don't see the corresponding entity has "Key" attribute on the ID column.
So I get compile time warning

Warning 4   Error 6002: The table/view 'XXXXXX' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.

Answer (score 0):

In your SqlServer:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionName() RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Viewname])
```

In your app, upgrade your model from database and import function **FunctionName**.

In your controller:

```
var some = db.**FunctionName()**.SingleOrDefault(c => c.field == someparam);
```